# Rails can't find my sqlite3 and table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Im a noob on rails.

I tried to scaffold a model msg.
it works finely when i use WEBrick server on a localhost.

But when i tried to access this page (/msgs) using apache+passenger on other client it shows "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

i checked the log file,it shows
"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: msgs: SELECT "msgs".* FROM "msgs"):"

i tried

> rails c
>   p=Msg.new

i guess there will be error,but it works fine.

I have no idea on what is happening,do i miss anything?

Regards.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error tells you that the table for msgs does not exist, you need to run rake db:migrate on the server you deployed your application to.

Comment: try rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Thanks a lot,not knowing why but it works,could you explain it for me?

Comment: Rails usually works with three different databases; development, test and production. When you deployed your application the production database was not migrated. So whenever you move or set up the application on a different server you need to run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=<the environment its running> to set up the database tables.